# How to fullscreen/maximize the size of a view in Swift / Xcode 6?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have a UIWebView that I'm trying to perfect on all devices. I have it working perfectly on the iPhone 5 but having troubles on iPad now.

In the Attributes Inspector, I've checked `Scale Pages To Fit`.
In the Size Inspector, I've tried to remove the preset dimensions but the 400x580 was automatically placed after I removed the previous values.

I'm trying to get a full size UIWebView to work on all devices in a Tabbed Application.

Any ideas? Thanks so much.

[image]